# How do I install the Perl DateTime module on Mac OSX 10.6

Tags: macos, perl, cpan

Ok, I know how to install Perl modules with cpan and have been doing it for years. But when I try to install the DateTime module on this particular mac, it fails, claiming that it cannot find a compiler.

Here is some of the output from attempting to install one of the prerequisites, Params::Validate: ( I get the same kinds of errors from attempting to install the module in question.)

```
Configuring Params-Validate-1.00
Running Build.PL
/usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/as: assembler (/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as or /usr/bin/../local/libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as) for architecture ppc not installed
Installed assemblers are:
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as for architecture x86_64
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/i386/as for architecture i386
lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//cc3Aefez.out (No such file or directory)
Warning: ExtUtils::CBuilder not installed or no compiler detected
Proceeding with configuration, but compilation may fail during Build
```

Why is Build.PL looking for a ppc compiler? If that is the problem where do I tell it (or cpan, or cpanm) that this machine is not a ppc box?

I'm running 10.6.8. The version of perl is v5.10.0 built for darwin-thread-multi-2level

I most definitely have the Developer tools installed.

I'm running cpan and cpanm via sudo.

I'd be grateful for any assistance anyone can offer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [known problem with Xcode on Lion](http://mjo.tc/atelier/2011/03/xcode4-perl.html), Apple couldn't help messing around with `nm`, breaking Perl again ([previously](http://use.perl.org/~jk2addict/journal/38503)) and who knows what else
- [p5p discussion](http://markmail.org/thread/j3s536r75u2q3has)
- [perlbrew's info](http://www.perlbrew.pl/FixLion.html)

[You are on an unsupported Perl.](http://p3rl.org/perl5140delta#Notice) [Upgrade to stable.](http://perl.org/get.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I edited Config_heavy.pl to remove the ppc and now I get:
`Running make for D/DR/DROLSKY/DateTime-0.70.tar.gz dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _Perl_Gthr_key_ptr Referenced from: /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/Digest/SHA/SHA.bundle Expected in: flat namespace dyld: Symbol not found: _Perl_Gthr_key_ptr Referenced from: /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/Digest/SHA/SHA.bundle Expected in: flat namespace Trace/BPT trap`

Answer (score 5):

I've got 10.7 installed which comes with Perl 5.12.3 installed. I did a CPAN install:

```
$ sudo cpan
password:
cpan> install DateTime
```

And, the whole thing works. Is this something you need for a third party file, or do you want to use this because you're familiar with this particular package?

There are several built in *Time* packages with [Perl 5.10](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.10.0/index-modules-T.html). Would one of these work for you? Otherwise, you might need to install `ExtUtils::CBuilder` and see if that helps.

Or, install a more modern version of Perl such as [ActiveState](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads) which is pretty simple to install, its `cpan` utility works pretty good on a Mac, and it's version 5.14 which is even newer than the version that comes with Lion.

Comment: It is almost like a third party - it is code I wrote for a client many many years ago that now needs some revisions. It actually runs on a server that has Date::Time, but I wanted to do the testing locally. The server is running 5.10.1, so I don't want to get too far away from that lest some other compatibility issues creep in. It is to some extent, stubbornness that is driving this for me now as I also have a local Debian box which, of course, just works as expected (in this regard anwyay).

Comment: After I installed this module on my system, all of the _Perl POD_ programs under /usr/bin lost their execute bit including `perldoc`. I had to do a `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/perl* /usr/bin/pod*` on the directory.

Answer (score 1):

I think what's happening is that the installer is trying to compile something (possibly an XS module) and to do that it needs to use the same compiler that was used to compile whichever version of Perl is on your system, and it can't find it.
Your best bet would be to install your own version of Perl 5.10 using [perlbrew](http://search.cpan.org/~gugod/App-perlbrew-0.41/bin/perlbrew) as this gaurantees the compiler is available (make sure you edit your .profile so Terminal uses your new Perl), then re-open Terminal, switch to the perlbrew version of Perl 5.10 and you should be fine from then on.

If you have problems installing the perlbrew Perl then as daxim noted above refer to the [Lion fix](http://www.perlbrew.pl/FixLion.html)